# After adding detection of browser language, the language href anchor (hl) stops working

Tags: php, html

I know how to detect language browser in PHP and also how to detect the language href anchor for switching to another.

My old codes which doesn't have `locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);`:

```
if (isset($_GET['hl'])) 
{
    $langOption = $_GET['hl'];
} 

else 
{
    $langOption = '';
}

switch ($langOption):
  case 'ca':
    $language = 'cat';
    break;
  case 'el':
    $language = 'el';
    break;
  case 'en':
    $language = 'en';
    break;
  case 'en_GB':
    $language = 'en_GB';
    break;
  case 'es':
    $language = 'es';
    break;
  case 'fr':
    $language = 'fr';
    break;
  case 'ka':
    $language = 'ka';
    break;
  case 'nl':
    $language = 'nl';
    break;
  case 'pt_PT':
    $language = 'pt_PT';
    break;
  case 'pt_BR':
    $language = 'pt_BR';
    break;
  case 'ro':
    $language = 'ro';
    break;
  default:
    $language = 'pt_BR';
    break;
endswitch;

require_once("idiomas/{$language}.php");
```

These old codes worked very for language href anchors. Like:

```
<a class="waves-effect" href="?hl=en_GB" name="en">English</a>
<a class="waves-effect" href="?hl=pt_BR" name="pt_BR">Português Brasileiro</a>
```

I changed to codes to condense, economise and shorten the codes. Here are new codes:

```
$language = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

if (isset($_GET['hl'])) 
{
    $lang = $_GET['hl'];

}

else 
{
    $lang = '';
}

switch ($lang):
  case $language:
    $language = $language;
    break;
  default:
    $language = $language;
    break;
endswitch;

require_once("idiomas/{$language}.php");
```

Only the detection of browser language worked very well, but the language href anchors (hl) do not work, because if you switch to Portuguese, the page still in English.

Similar like:

```
switch ($lang):
  case "en":
    $language = "en";
    break;
  case "en_GB":
    $language = "en_GB";
    break;
  case "pt_BR":
    $language = "pt_BR";
    break;
  case "pt_PT":
    $language = "pt_PT";
    break;
endswitch;
```

But I wouldn't like to repeat these old codes. I want to keep condensing and shortening the same new codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what the switch statement is doing here?
The reason it's not working is because you're not using the $lang variable for anything, it's just setting $language to itself for all cases.

I think this would do what you want :

```
$language = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

if (isset($_GET['hl'])) 
{
    $language = $_GET['hl'];
}
```

As query params can be modified by the user, I'd also suggest using in_array to check that the value is something expected.